# c# check page has loaded before redirecting

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, response.redirect

I've have a page which currently does a small task then redirects to a 3rd party website.

The redirect is triggered by a `Response.Redirect();`

Now I want to add another function but this time it's javascript.

I'm using the following method to add the javascript to the page:

```
if (!page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(key))
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), key, script, false);
}
```

The function of the javascript is to track a sale, so I need the page to render it and trigger the track before moving on.

Anyone know if this will work or not, and if not how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use `Response.Redirect()` to handle redirecting the user anymore. Instead, you'll have to redirect through JavaScript after your start-up script executes. I would simply tack on:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.whateveryourredirecturlis.com");
```

To the end of your existing start-up script.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your javascript.

```
document.onready = function () { window.location = "http://yoururl"; };
```